# PowerShell Remove-Item silently doesn't remove a single file

Tags: powershell

I have mixed together a PowerShell script that browses folders recursively searching for too low resolution pictures.

I have googled for a solution for couple of hours and so far I haven't managed to get those images deleted. So what's the deal with this?

Turns out that square brackets in file names were causing problems. But now Remove-Item complains that the files are used by another process, which I assume is this script itself.

```
$kuveja = 0
$pikkusii = 0
[void][reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("system.drawing")

function Get-Image{
process {
        $file = $_
        [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName)  |
        ForEach-Object{
            $_ | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty FullName ('{0}' -f $file.FullName)
        }
    }
}

$path = 'H:\Juttui\'
Get-ChildItem $path\* -Include *.jpg, *.jpeg* -Recurse | ? {
    $kuva = $_ | Get-Image
    if($kuva.Width -lt 960 -and $kuva.Height -lt 960){
        Write-Host $_.FullName -fore red
        Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force
        $pikkusii++
    }
    elseif($kuva.Width -lt 540 -or $kuva.Height -lt 540){
        Write-Host $_.FullName -fore yellow
        Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force
        $pikkusii++
    }
    $kuveja++
}

Write-Host "Pics browsed: $kuveja" -fore green
Write-Host "Small: $pikkusii" -fore green
```

Please understand that I am complete noob in PowerShell and I don't know a better place to ask this than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `$kuva` reference is keeping the file open. Try performing the `.Dispose()` method before trying to remove the object. So something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $path\* -Include *.jpg, *.jpeg* -Recurse | ? {
    $kuva = $_ | Get-Image
    if($kuva.Width -lt 960 -and $kuva.Height -lt 960){
        Write-Host $_.FullName -fore red
        $kuva.dispose()
        Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force
        $pikkusii++
    }
    elseif($kuva.Width -lt 540 -or $kuva.Height -lt 540){
        Write-Host $_.FullName -fore yellow
        $kuva.dispose()
        Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force
        $pikkusii++
    }
    $kuveja++
}
```

Comment: Ohh nice catch. If this is the case, then sometimes when the handle is closed (like if powershell were closed or the computer restarted) the file may then disappear (obviously not ideal but it's a reason why `Remove-Item` would act successful instead of throwing an error).

Answer (score 0):

```powershell
Get-ChildItem $path\* -Include *.jpg, *.jpeg* -Recurse | ? {
    # ...
}
```

`?` means `Where-Object`, but I think what you really want is `ForEach-Object`. The alias for `ForEach-Object` is `%`, but you should not use aliases in scripts for this very reason (it's less clear).

Try this:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem $path\* -Include *.jpg, *.jpeg* -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # ...
}
```

If that doesn't work, you have `Write-Host` calls before the removes so are you seeing the red and yellow text that indicates the remove should be happening? You should try to run your script in ISE. Set a breakpoint right before the `Remove-Item` call, then step through the code.

Comment: Yes I can see the red file names. No file seems to fit the yellow criteria. Unfortunately ForEach-Object gave me no more luck. Huh, this is weird. I set break point and it stops correctly on first match, but when I step into, the code just goes on and no errors of any kind are shown. Could it be that the full name contains spaces?